# Null Pointer Exception al cargar un JTextField

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo mi clase Auto

```
public class Auto {

    int id_auto;
    String modelo;
    String color;
    int anio;
    String marca;

    public int getId_auto() {
        return id_auto;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getAnio() {
        return anio;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setId_auto(int id_auto) {
        this.id_auto = id_auto;
    }

    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setAnio(int anio) {
        this.anio = anio;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public Auto(int id_auto, String modelo, String color, int anio, String marca) {
        this.id_auto = id_auto;
        this.modelo = modelo;
        this.color = color;
        this.anio = anio;
        this.marca = marca;
    }



}
```

Un metodo en mi clase Gestor para modificar el Auto que el usuario seleccione de un JTable

```
public Auto modificarAuto(int id)
    {
        Auto a = null;
        String sql = "SELECT a.id_auto, a.modelo, a.color, a.anio, m.marca FROM auto a, marca m WHERE a.id_marca = m.id_marca AND id_auto = ?";

        try(Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
                PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sql);)
        {
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next())
            {
                int id_auto = rs.getInt("id_auto");
                String modelo = rs.getString("modelo");
                String color = rs.getString("color");
                int anio = rs.getInt("anio");
                String marca = rs.getString("marca");

                a = new Auto(id_auto,modelo,color,anio,marca);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }


        return a;
    }
```

Y la ventana que se abrira con los JTextFields cargados con los datos correspondientes.

```
ModificarAuto(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
    Auto a = ge.modificarAuto(this.id);
    txtId.setText(String.valueOf(a.getId_auto()));
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al user el metodo .setText me salta el error de NullPointerException. No tengo problemas para mostrar el resultado de **a.getId_auto** por consola, pero si a la hora de guardarlo en un JTextField

Comment: ¿De dónde sale esta variable: `txtId`?

Comment: Del JFrame ModificarAuto. Lo solucione añadiendo un this();. Antes del this.id = id;
La verdad nose porque la ausencia de ese método me generaba el error.

Comment: `this();` llama de nuevo al constructor de la clase. ¿Si lo quitas y pones esto: `this.txtId.setText(String.valueOf(a.getId_auto()));` no funciona? Me da la impresión de que puede haber un pequeño error de lógica en tu programa.

Comment: Lo quite, puse eso y no funciona. El codigo no es mio lamentablemente. El error de logica puede deberse a las pocas posibilidades de pasar los datos de un JTable de un JFrame a otos objetos de otro JFrame

Comment: @LucasDavid ya solucionaste tu problema?

Comment: Si! Me quedo la duda de que hace realmente el this(); que me faltaba. De sabarlo podria ponerlo como respuesta para que no sea tan poco especifica.

Comment: @juliocpiro . Probado y error tambien. Al parecer el this(); al principio del metodo es importante

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado agregando un *this();* al comienzo de mi metodo

```
ModificarAuto(int id)
    {
        this();
        id_a = id;
        Auto a = ge.modificarAuto(id_a);
        txtId.setText(String.valueOf(a.getId_auto()));
        txtModelo.setText(a.getModelo());
        txtColor.setText(a.getColor());
        txtAnio.setText(String.valueOf(a.getAnio()));
        cboMarca.setSelectedItem(a.getMarca());
    }
```